# unique random key redis lua script

Tags: lua, redis

Absolutely new to lua.. just started 1 hr ago :) . I want to generate randomid and make sure that key with same id doesn't exists in redis. So i have written below code in lua

```
local get_random_id
get_random_id = function(id)
    local id_exists = redis.call("EXISTS", id)
    if id_exists == 0 then
         return id 
    end
    local newid = randomstring(3)
    get_random_id(newid)
end

local id = randomstring(3)
local existingid = "abc"
return get_event_id(existingid)
```

It works fine if i pass the key which doesn't exists in the redis it returns me a new random key. However if key exists in redis it returns me nil.

More Info: I MONITOR redis and found script is generating the random string and checking in redis but somehow it returning nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning the new random id from your recursive call.

Replace the line:

```
get_random_id(newid)
```

with:

```
return get_random_id(newid)
```

BTW, you can replace the definition of your function with just:

```
local function get_random_id(id)
    -- ... code ..
end
```

instead of

```
local get_random_id
get_random_id = function(id)
    -- ... code ..
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but if i put the return there what if this number is also exists in the redis? I think i am messing up in code somewhere.. What i want it to generate a random number and check for existence in redis until i get a number which doesnt exists

Comment: and by the way if i change function to local function get_random_id(id) it generates error "Script attempted to access unexisting global variable" as redis interpreter cant access global variables

Comment: Discard my first comment.. May be i am sleeping.. thanks for the response.. it works :)

Comment: @Atul If it solved your problem you may consider accepting my answer.

Comment: by the way if u can help me out with the padding also so if number is 1 i want to pad it to 0 and make it 0001

Comment: @Atul Sure, but you should post another question (after searching SO to avoid it being marked as duplicate). This is the way SO works. It is not an IRC channel, forum or BBS, it is a Q&A site, so the emphasis is on having good questions + qood answers, not an archive of discussion threads. Happy coding! :-)

Comment: Make sense.. anyway found out the way as lua support string.rep functions.. thanks mate..

Comment: I got this error: `Script attempted to access unexisting global variable 'randomstring'`

Comment: @MarkHu the OP's snippet cannot stand on its own. `randomstring` was a function that was already defined somewhere else (in redis?). Probably you just tried to execute that snippet without the context it lived in.